# How to access this.var inside an object literal function

Tags: javascript

I have come across this code

```
var person = {
    name: "joseph",
    age: 33,
    favSong: function killingInTheTameOf(){
        this.lyrics = "Those who died are justified";
    }
};

document.write(person.lyrics); //doesn't work
```

my question is about the **this.lyrics** variable,
what is the meaning of this?
how do i access it?
what does this refer to exactly? person?
i have read about this but none of the cases i learnd about covers this

Comment: You've never called `person.favSong`, which creates the property, hence the said property is not created at the time you're trying to access it.

Comment: `person.favSong(); console.log(person.lyrics)`

Comment: why experts always comment their answer and losing the option to be selected as best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `favSong` in order to create the property `lyrics`.

```js
var person = {
    name: "joseph",
    age: 33,
    favSong: function killingInTheTameOf(){
        this.lyrics = "Those who died are justified";
    }
};

person.favSong();
document.write(person.lyrics); //worksss
```